# DFS function for finding the clusters of same symbol in 2D matrix

Tags: java

I am trying to write a DFS code for finding the clusters of size greater than or equal to 2 inside a 2D matrix of integers. I am trying to write the DFS for that. Here I am unable to get any output inside the win cluster list of Cluster Object. Can anybody suggest what is going wrong. I have written a DFS function that calls for all neighbouring locations(horizontally and vertically).

Also checking for the valid condition for checking whether the indices are inside the  row and column constraints. When the DFS is terminating I am checking for the condition if count of cluster is greater than 2 then I'll add it to the win clusters list else simply return.Please suggest why am I not getting any value in the win_clusters list.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class sample {

    static int grid[][]= {{1,3,0,4,0},
                          {3,2,0,0,1},
                          {0,4,1,0,1},
                          {4,0,0,0,2},
                          {2,4,0,2,4}};

    static int ROW;
    static int COLUMN;

    public static int[][] grid_creation(int numRows, int numCols){
        ROW= numRows;
        COLUMN=numCols;
        int [][]grid = new int[numRows][numCols];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i<numRows ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<numCols; j++){
                grid[i][j]= rand.nextInt(5);
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

    public static void print_matrix(int[][]matrix){
        for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(boolean[][] visited, int row, int col){
        if(row<0 ||col<0 || row>=ROW || col>=COLUMN || visited[row][col] )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static class Cluster{
        List<Integer> cluster_symbol_positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int symbol = -1;
        int count = 0;
        int win = 0;

        public void create_new_Cluster(){
            cluster_symbol_positions = new ArrayList<>();
            symbol = -1;
            count = 0;
            win= 0;
        }
        public List<Integer> get_cluster_symbol_positions(){
            return cluster_symbol_positions;
        }

        public int getSymbol(){return symbol;}
        public void setSymbol(int a){symbol = a;}
        public int getCount(){return count;}

        public  void add_to_cluster(int row1, int col1 ){
            int row = row1;
            int col = col1;
            cluster_symbol_positions.add(getReelPositionNumber(row,col));
            count++;
        }
        public  int cluster_win(Cluster cluster){
            int win_amount = 0;
            //return win amount from the paytable

            return win_amount;
        }
    }



    public static void DFS(int[][] grid,List<Cluster> win_clusters) {
        int h = grid.length;
        if (h == 0)
            return;
        int l = grid[0].length;

        //created visited array
        boolean [][] visited = new boolean[h][l];

        System.out.println("Depth-First Search: ");
        for( int i =0; i< ROW ; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ;j<COLUMN; j++){
                if(!visited[i][j]) {
                    DFSUtil(grid, i, j, visited, win_clusters);

                }
            }
        }

    }
       static Cluster global_cluster= new Cluster();
       static int cluster_length =0;

    public static void DFSUtil(int[][]grid, int row, int col, boolean[][] visited, List<Cluster>win_clusters){

        if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= ROW|| col >= COLUMN || visited[row][col] ) {
            if(global_cluster.getCount()>=2) win_clusters.add(global_cluster);
            return;
        }

        int symbol = grid[row][col];
        visited[row][col] = true;
         cluster_length++;
         global_cluster.add_to_cluster(row,col);
         global_cluster.setSymbol(symbol);

        if(isValid(visited, row+1, col) && grid[row+1][col]==symbol){
            DFSUtil(grid, row+ 1, col,visited,win_clusters); // go down
        }
        if(isValid(visited, row-1, col) && grid[row-1][col]==symbol) {
            DFSUtil(grid, row - 1, col, visited, win_clusters); //go up
        }

        if(isValid(visited, row, col+1) && grid[row][col+1]==symbol){
            DFSUtil(grid, row, col + 1,visited,win_clusters); //go right
        }
        if(isValid(visited, row, col-1) && grid[row][col-1]==symbol){
            DFSUtil(grid, row, col - 1,visited,win_clusters); // go left
        }
    }

    public static int getReelPositionNumber(int row, int col) {
        return (row*COLUMN) + col;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getReelPositionsIndex(int positionNumber) {

        List<Integer> tempData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int numReels =COLUMN;
        int display = ROW;
        if(positionNumber >= numReels*display)
            throw new RuntimeException( positionNumber+" is out of range "+ numReels*display +"(rows*cols) in the game." );
        if(positionNumber < numReels) {
            tempData.add(0);
            tempData.add(positionNumber);
        } else if(positionNumber == (numReels*display)) {
            tempData.add(display - 1);
            tempData.add(numReels - 1);
        } else {
            int row = positionNumber / numReels;
            int col = positionNumber % numReels;
            tempData.add(row);
            tempData.add(col);
        }
        return tempData;
    }




    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Modified function for cluster win ");
        List<Cluster> win_clusters = new ArrayList<Cluster>();
        DFS(grid,win_clusters);
        print_matrix(grid);
        System.out.println(win_clusters.size());

    }
}
```